# One Page Checkout - checkout progress wrapper not shown

Tags: php, magento, mage, onepage-checkout

i updated a magento store from 1.6 to 1.9. I got some problems with the one page checkout. At first i cant order anything. I resolved this with adding the formkey. The 2nd problem is that this:

```
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('checkout_progress_wrapper');?>
```

does not show anything. I am using my own theme and checkt out the old xml with the new one but there seem to be no changes. The div isn't even parsed empty it's juzst not shown. Hope someone can help me.

Comment: how you upgrade your magento ?

Comment: i downloaded the 1.9 version from the site and copied the files over my old  ones. Therefore i took a backup. AFter this i updated the extensions over magento connect.

Comment: try with default magento theme.

Comment: I am simply new with magento... where can i change the theme ?

Comment: navigate to `system ->configuration ` in admin then click on `design` menu from left menu. and change `Current Package Name` to `base`

Comment: Thx, the steps are shown now but i cant use the base theme it has to work with my own theme. The site looks like total crap now.

Comment: is your current theme is a paid theme?

Comment: I don't know if it's a paied theme. Guess it's not

Comment: ok, then do one thing. take backup of your `checkout` and replace that by default theme `checkout` folder. here you can find default checkout folder
`app\design\frontend\base\default\template`

Comment: this is going to crash my onepage checkout. The style is horrible and after step 3 it doesnt work anymore.

Comment: you have to restyle your theme according to magento 1.9. there is no other option beside that.

Comment: you might be face issue in admin too.

Comment: The style is correct in my own theme. It would be really nice if this theme would work. I guess using the base theme and restyle it isn't my job.

Comment: current theme is according to magento 1.6 and you updated that to 1.9 so you have to make that theme according to 1.9 if you want it to work fine.

Comment: Okay so i will give it a try. Thx for your help. :)

Comment: In a different way.. it was a xml problem nothhing about the design. Now the 4 progress divs are shown but the paymnet method div is totally empty. The 3 other divs are shown correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Here are some step for upgrading magento

1. Take a backup of current database and current 1.6 code. place maintenance.flag file inside 1.6 code folder to put website offline.
2. Download latest magento from the http://www.magentocommerce.com/download
3. Remove all folders and files from your 1.6 code except `maintenance.flag` (but you should have backup somewhere) and place all folders and files from the 1.9.x
4. Now from your 1.6 merge your following custom folders into the 1.9.x

   - Community `app/code/community`
   - Local `app/code/local`
   - Media
   - your theme or package (`app/design/frontend/default/<your theme>` or `app/design/frontend/<your package>`)
   - custom folders from Skin (both for adminhtml and frontend).
   - copy your custom xml files from `app/etc/modules/` to current `app/etc/modules/`
   - any custom admin theme folder from `adminhtml/default/yourtheme`.
   - copy your custom folders from `adminhtml/default/default/` (1.6) to adminhtml/default/default/ (1.9.x).
   - custom js files if any from `app/js/`.
5. Now go to `app/etc/local.xml`.Edit database details their.put your database username and password and database name.
6. Remove `maintenance.flag` file and check the site in the browser. it is done.